# Spring repository query with two table

Tags: java, sql, database, spring

I have a Database with two tables :

1) NumberEntity

```
|------|-------|--------|
|  id  |numero | volume |
|------|-------|--------|
|  1   |    1  |   1    |
|------|-------|--------|
|  2   |    1  |   2    |
|------|-------|--------|
|  3   |    2  |   1    |
|------|-------|--------|
```

2) ArticleEntity

```
|------|-------|------------|
|  id  |Article| numbers_id |
|------|-------|------------|
|  5   |    7  |   1        |
|------|-------|------------|
|  6   |    5  |   2        |
|------|-------|------------|
|  7   |    6  |   3        |
|------|-------|------------|
```

Where numbers_id is the relation with the first table.
I would like to extract with a query through the first 
table, the articles ordered by article desc.
I don't know how I can do it, I started with this query:

```
public List<NumberEntity> findByVolumeAndNumero(String volume, String number);
```

I got the list of the articles but the first is the article number 7, instead I would like to extract like first article the number 5, 6 and 7.

These are my model:

```
    @Entity
    public class NumberEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String volume;
    private String numero;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="numbers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ArticleEntity> articles = new ArrayList<ArticleEntity>();
```

The other:

```
 @Entity
    public class ArticleEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String article;
    @ManyToOne
    private NumberEntity numbers;
```

So I need a query like this one (even if itsn't correct, but it's only pseudo code):

```
public List<NumberEntity> findByVolumeAndNumeroOrderByArticleDesc(String volume, String number);
```

The problem is, that I didn't understand how to join the other table with a single query using Spring

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891571/crudrepository-join-single-field-from-other-table-to-entity-as-readonly.please check this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with using **Query**  .Try this code .

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM number n join article a on n.id = a.numbers_id order by a.id  ")
```

Comment: Thank you, but the query launch an exception. And I need to pass two parameter: volume and numero. Could you help me better ? Is there a maner using Spring JPA query ?

Comment: You are great ! I solved according your advise, your solution was near my request: @Query(value = "SELECT a.* FROM numberentity n INNER JOIN articleentity a on n.id = (select n.id from numberentity n where n.volume = ?1 AND n.numero = ?2)AND n.id = a.numbers_id order by a.article asc", nativeQuery=true)

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to not create bidirectional relationship because when you are making a select you will face a loop; in your case it is enough to create a relation ManyToOne from article to number.
The query should look like this:

```
@Query("select * from ArticleEntity article inner join article.numbers number where article.numbers.volume=:volume and article.numbers.id=:id")
    List<ArticleEntity> findAll(@Param("volume") String volume , @Param("id") long id);
```

Try this query (p.s. check the name of fields to be the same as they are in java class (entity) )

After you can add to your query order desc by article.number.volume or what after you would like...

Also please read about [Criteria](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm) . This way to write query is much more simple because has some method which implement a lot of SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT ae FROM ArticleEntity ae WHERE ae.numbers.volume = :volume AND ae.numbers.numero = :numero ORDER BY ae.article DESC).setParameter("volume", volume).setParameter("numero", numero)
```

If you are using session you can swap entityManager with it.

Comment: I'm not using session

Comment: You can inject entityManager to your repository through @PersistanceContext then that query will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM ArticleEntity a, NumberEntity n WHERE ...")
```